# Calculate the area.

Tags: calculus

$$\int_{0}^{1/6} \sec(\pi x)dx$$

I've tried u-substitution but nothing seems to work. I've tried IntegralCalculator.net, and I'm still not convinced it's giving me the correct answer. I would appreciate anyone who could solve this step-by-step. Thanks.

Comment: Just substitute $u=\pi x$ and adjust the bounds accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your trouble is understanding how to integrate secant.

Recall that $\frac{d}{dx}(\sec(x) + \tan(x)) = \sec(x)(\sec(x)+\tan(x))$

So, we can use *u*-substitution such that ...

$$u=\sec(x) + \tan(x) \implies u' = \sec(x) \cdot u \implies \sec(x) = \frac{u'}{u} = (\ln(u))'$$

Thus, after putting back our $u$, we've found that $\sec(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \ln(\sec(x) + \tan(x))$.

This is quite useful for your integral: $\int \sec(t)dt = \ln(\sec(t) + \tan(t)) + c$. Now, letting $u = \pi x\ldots$, we have $dx = \frac{du}{\pi}$. Performing the substitution, we find $$\int\sec(\pi x)dx = \frac{\log(\tan(u) + \sec(u))}{\pi} + c= \frac{\log(\tan(\pi x) + \sec(\pi x))}{\pi} + c$$

**Applying your bounds, we get $\frac{\log(3)}{2\pi}\approx 0.17$**

Comment: Thank you. I understand the concept now.

Comment: I think that $\frac{u'}{u}=(\ln(u))'$and not $\ln(u)$